# Redirect to custom design 500 error page in PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

I am working on the E-Commerce site and use CodeIgniter framework in PHP.I have two panels: 1) front and 2) Admin.

During page load or URL redirection if 'Internal Server Error' occur, I want to display my custom design page 500_error_admin.php for admin and 500_error_front.php for front UI.

Let me clear 500_error_admin.php and 500_error_front.php both pages have different design.

I try this code but I can't get success

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    #Directly give the path of page
    ErrorDocument 500 http://localhost/myproject/errors/500_admin.php
    #Also try with create controller and call method
    #ErrorDocument 500 http://localhost/myproject/admin/Error/show_500    
</IfModule>
```

**Controller Method**

```
class Error extends CI_Controller {    
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function error_500() {        
        $this->load->view('errors/500_admin');      
    }
}
```

Is this possible in codeigniter which i looking for?

Please suggest me, how can i do it with alternative ways?

Answer (score 0):

```
myproject/application/config/database.php

SET $db['default']['db_debug'] to FALSE instead of TRUE .

$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can archive by owerride core exaption controller for both admin side and client side, follow the given steps:

**Step:1** Add subclass prefix: $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_'; in your config file(system/application/config/config.php)

**Step:2** Create MY_Exceptions.php file in you directory(system/application/libraries) and add bellow code

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions{
    function MY_Exceptions(){
        parent::CI_Exceptions();
    }

    function show_404($page=''){    

        $this->config =& get_config();
        $base_url = $this->config['base_url'];

        $_SESSION['error_message'] = 'Error message';
        header("location: ".$base_url.'error.html');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Thats it! Not your error page will redirect to the error.html page. Hope this will help you!

Greetings!

Comment: @Nidhi Try this http://www.thephpcode.com/blog/view/how-to-create-custom-404-page-with-codeigniter.html. it might be help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your custom page for showing error. codeigniter 3 already has default error page. if you want to change error page then open config.php inside application/config/config.php

Inside config.php find Error Views Directory Path

```
$config['error_views_path'] = APPPATH.'/views/errors/'; //path to you error view directory
```

then change to you directory error views. inside views there is 2 directory.[cli,html]
where cli view handle while you access your website throught cmd or terminal.
and html view handle while you access your website throught browser.

in this case you need to change design for html.

inside html there is 5 error page defined by ci.

```
-application/views/html/error_404.php // while page doesn't exist
-application/views/html/error_db.php // while error on db such as configuration and etc
-application/views/html/error_exception.php // error exception
-application/views/html/error_general.php // error general
-application/views/html/error_php.php
```

you can change your 500_admin.php rename 500_admin.php to error_general.php. for the variable message you need to open default error_general.php and paste into your new view 
remember put them inside application/views/errors/html.
so your error page structure folder will be look like this

```
application/views/errors/html/error_general.php
```

for detail explanation you can see the documentatuion [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html?highlight=error)

Comment: Thank you for help.But using this we can display custom design page for error.but while a developer is a work on specific module then it also display custom design page either showing an error message.And it also display same error page for both admin and front  panel.I want different for both.

Comment: first you need to make constant value. forex define( 'APP_TYPE', "admin"); in your constructor or using $_SESSION to put your current state. in the view using if to separate them. <?php if (APP_TYPE=="admin"): ?>your design for admin <?php else:?> your design for front end <?php endif; ?> for detail alternatif PHP Syntax for View Files https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/alternative_php.html?highlight=echo#alternate-php-syntax-for-view-files

Comment: i will suggest you to split them into different app.

Comment: Individual app working very fine.but this is not the correct solution.**I have to do this in a similar app with multi-panels.**

Comment: how to define that you are in admin or front app? are you use http://example.com/admin and http://example.com for front end? you can put your error page in different dir and change that in your controller with $this->config->set_item('error_views_path', APPPATH.'/views/errors_admin/'); for example. the problem is how to define that you are in admin or front end

Answer (score 0):

This is a old question, but this is my solution:

in application/core

```
<?php


class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions
{
    public function show_error($heading, $message, $template = 'error_general', $status_code = 500)
    {
        $message = '<p>'.(is_array($message) ? implode('</p><p>', $message) : $message).'</p>';
        $_SESSION['500_error_heading'] = $heading;
        $_SESSION['500_error_message'] = $message;

        redirect('error/server');
    }
}
```

in config/routes.php

```
$route['error/server'] = 'errorController/error_server';
```

in errorController

```
public function error_server()
    {
        $session = new SessionHelper();

        $data['heading'] = $session->get('500_error_heading');
        $data['message'] = $session->get('500_error_message');

        $session->unset('500_error_heading');
        $session->unset('500_error_message');

        $this->CI->load->view_template('errors/html/error_general', $data);
    }
```